# onclick function it's working only after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have **(onclick)** function code for image view that code is working perfectly the issue is it is working when i click second time only. I can't understand what is the issue is please help me to fix this issue. I attached the code below..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function showimage(z)
        {
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'+z);
                var img = document.getElementById('myImg'+z);
                var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01'+z);
                var captionText = document.getElementById('caption'+z);

                img.onclick = function ()
                {
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                    modalImg.src = this.src;
                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                }
        }
    </script>

<span>
      <img src="<?php echo $u_pimg; ?>" alt="" class="newsize" id="myImg<?php echo $p_id; ?>" onclick="showimage(<?php echo $p_id; ?>)">
    enter code here
</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First u r binding the "showimage" method to be called when u click on the image then u r binding

```
function ()
                {
                    modal.style.display = "block";
                    modalImg.src = this.src;
                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
                }
```

on click of the image. So u should not bind the event again on the image tag.

remove either onclick="showimage()" from ur html tag or remove img.onclick from the JS code.

write it like :

```
function showimage(z)
        {
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'+z);
                var img = document.getElementById('myImg'+z);
                var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01'+z);
                var captionText = document.getElementById('caption'+z);

                 modal.style.display = "block";
                    modalImg.src = img.src;
                    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }
```

and it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what your code is doing, 'cause you provide only small piece of it. But you definitely have a completely unnecessary `onlick` inside your `showimage` function. Try to remove the inner `img.onclick` perhaps?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

        function showimage(z)
        {
                var modal = document.getElementById('myModal'+z);
                var img = document.getElementById('myImg'+z);
                var modalImg = document.getElementById('img01'+z);
                var captionText = document.getElementById('caption'+z);

                modal.style.display = "block";
                modalImg.src = img.src; // <- replace this with img
                captionText.innerHTML = img.alt;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: If i remove the onclick it's working in first click but image is not coming

Comment: Try to replace `this` with `img`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: is there any possible way to contact you get some support like Facebook

Comment: What do you mean by `some support like Facebook`? :) And why did you check the wrong answer as the right one? From what you said before - his version should not be working.

Comment: No is there anyway i can contact you like Facebook or Other social media to get your support

Comment: Why would you want a dedicated support (it's costly)? Post your questions on StackOverflow and you will be fine.